# YouTube Offline Playlist

Tags: youtube, offline

It has been a while since I am using the `YouTube's` offline video feature. But there is one thing which is annoying me off late.

I have set of `YouTube` videos saved for offline view, and it seems `YouTube` app in android add all of them in Play List. **I did not created this play list manuall**y. But as soon as I add a new video for offline view, `YouTube` app automatically add it into this so called *Offline*  playlist.

The issue is, when I play, say first video from that offline play list and when it is over, app picks up another video from offline Play list and plays it. **I don't want this to happen**.

I only want to play just 1 video and when it is done, app should just wait, instead of picking up a video from play list. This is how YouTube itself work, when it is not playing offline videos. It waits for user to pick the next video.

I don't want to adjust the sequence in which these videos are played. I want to play only single video at a time from that Offline play list(which is really created automatically by YouTube).

YouTube app version is **11.13.56**

Is there a way?

Comment: See if settings> auto-play is enabled. Disable that

Comment: @beeshyams There don't seems to be any option for auto-play enable/disable in Settings of youTube App. My YouTube app version is **11.13.56**

Comment: @beeshyams Oops I found it under same path in my app too. However, it is in Disabled state already. I am pretty sure this Autoplay is applicable on Normal YouTube viewing and not for Offline videos. As I said in my Q, that my normal youTube app does not autoplay. Its only an issue with Offline videos. They are all added into play list (again this play list is not created by me) and YouTube start playing them one after the other.

Comment: I was guessing that it is related to off line also- obviously wrong there